# Find CFLAGS and LDFLAGS equivalent in linux

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to figure out what is the equivalent paths of these in Linux.

I downloaded the `openssl` package `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`

```
//#cgo windows CFLAGS: "-IC:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64/include"
//#cgo windows LDFLAGS: "-LC:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64/lib" -llibcrypto
```

Comment: On a typical system, headers would be in `/usr/include`, libraries in `/usr/lib`. But this can depend on a great many things, like the Linux distribution, system architecture, package manager, etc.

Comment: Where do you plan to install the software?  `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib` might be appropriate; `/usr/local/openssl/include` and `/usr/local/openssl/lib` might be appropriate; `/opt/openssl/include` and `/opt/openssl/lib` might be appropriate.  You could even think about installing them in `/usr/include` and `/usr/lib` or `/lib` — or you might need to use `/usr/lib64` and/or `/lib64` — but then you're treading on territory controlled by the system and may run into problems over upgrades, etc.  It depends on how your system is setup.

Comment: That package installs a file for pkgconfig (`libssl.pc`, use `dpkg-query -L` to find the exact path that was installed), so you can find the desired flags with `pkg-config --cflags libssl` and `pkg-config --libs libssl`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to find flags needed to build using that installed package, then `pkg-config`:

```sh
]$ pkg-config --cflags openssl

]$ pkg-config --libs openssl
-lssl -lcrypto
```

So you don't need any special `-I` nor `-L` flags, because the includes and libraries are already in the system paths, you only need `-l` flags.

If that's not what you want, then you can just query the content of the package and see where the files are:

```sh
]$ dpkg-query -L libssl-dev
/.
/usr
/usr/include
/usr/include/openssl
/usr/include/openssl/aes.h
/usr/include/openssl/asn1.h
...
```

and do with that information whatever you need.